# Выравнивание блока по вертикали и ширина по содержимому

Tags: css, html, width

```css
.description-wrap {
  background: #FFD700;
  width: 1200px;
  height: 600px;
  text-align: center;
}

.description-table {
  display: table;
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.description-cell {
  border: 1px dashed red;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.description-text {
  border-top: 3px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #000;
  padding: 15px 0;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #000;
}

.description-text:first-child {
  margin-bottom: 5%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="description-wrap">
    <div class="description-table">
      <div class="description-cell">
        <div class="description-text">БИРЮЧИЙ ОСТРОВ</div>
        <div class="description-text">АЗОВО-СИВАШСКИЙ НАЦИОНАЛЬНЫЙ
          <br>ПРИРОДНЫЙ ПАРК</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Проблема состоит в том, что нужно в блоках div сделать ширину по содержимому. Хочу оставить верхнюю и нижнюю рамку (наподобе

---

) для стилизации. [Вот так](http://joxi.ru/KAg5wZECgEP5Xm)

Буду благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`display: table` + `margin: 0 auto` для `description-text`:

```css
.description-wrap {
  background: #FFD700;
  width: 1200px;
  height: 600px;
  text-align: center;
}

.description-table {
  display: table;
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.description-cell {
  border: 1px dashed red;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.description-text {
  display: table;
  margin: 0px auto;
  border-top: 3px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #000;
  padding: 15px 0;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #000;
}

.description-text:first-child {
  margin-bottom: 5%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="description-wrap">
    <div class="description-table">
      <div class="description-cell">
        <div class="description-text">БИРЮЧИЙ ОСТРОВ</div>
        <div class="description-text">АЗОВО-СИВАШСКИЙ НАЦИОНАЛЬНЫЙ
          <br>ПРИРОДНЫЙ ПАРК</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Спасибо за экспресс ответ.